# Closing questions resolved by "you should update to the next version" as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Today I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891891/log4j2-properties-monitorinterval-not-working/) during review.

In short, the conclusion was that the problem was actually a bug in the library, which was resolved in a later version.

Often, when having an issue with specific open-source library, OPs are redirected to the repository of said library and are told to open an issue there (which, in this case would be resolved by the update mentioned in the answers).

While it is *possible* that someone, someday will install an old-enough version of the library and run into this problem, this option becomes unlikely as time goes by. However, generally, a new user would use a more recent version, which has this bug fixed.

So - I'm thinking whether this is close enough to "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" (*technically*, it *can* be reproduced by obtaining the offending version somehow, but *practically*, the probability of anybody running into this problem is small and getting smaller).

I'm not saying that the information in that Q&A is not valuable (hence: meriting deletion), I just consider it unlikely that an answer better than those already posted would ever appear, so, **is there a point in keeping such questions [open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583)**?

Comment: It's a boring question... not a bad question. Yet both produce the same effect: shun away experts.

Comment: We close things to prevent answers, if it isn't going to get anymore answers (and you don't want it deleted), what's the point in closing it?

Comment: @TinyGiant indicating that it is OT (if that is indeed the case).

Comment: But it isn't OT, why would you want to indicate that if it isn't that?

Comment: @TinyGiant Arguably, it's not that clear cut (this is the whole point of the question)... See answer comments...

Comment: @Dev-iL The answer is correct in that such a question is not off-topic. The comments by Braiam on the answer below are not indicative of community consensus or procedure, and are misleading at best. The point of this operation is not to close every question that comes into the site. Determining the usefulness of a question for future viewers is extremely subjective. That close reason should **only** be used for typographical errors or errors that cannot be reproduced _at all_. If you're having trouble making a close reason fit, it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "A problem that can no longer be reproduced" close reason does not include the case when the problem was caused by a bug in the library which has been fixed in an update. That problem is still clearly reproducible (by downloading the old library version - as you have also said yourself) and will be reproducible in the future as well.

Just because it might seem unlikely that a new user installs an older version it's not impossible. It's especially quite likely that a lot of people who have been using the older version are not able to update (for different reasons) and might run into the same problem in the future.

And while it's probably true that there will never be a better answer to this question other that *"this issue has been fixed in version X"* there currently is no close reason for that and I don't think we need one. The number of question that can be perfectly answered without any room for improvement is quite small and therefore not enough of a reason to introduce a *"This question is perfectly answered and there is nothing anyone could add to it"* - close reason.

If a question like this receives new answers that say the same thing months or years after the original answers (probably by low-rep users) you can just flag those answers to be deleted.

Closing these questions would also kind of indicate that they are off-topic and therefore not a good fit for SO, which isn't really true. There is nothing wrong with the question itself and similar questions can still be asked and are generally on-topic. That's another problem I can see with closing these questions.

Comment: Actually, the close reason goes beyond that "While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.**" Future readers will be the less likely finding themselves in this situation, as most of the developers have a knack for using the cutting edge.

Comment: @Braiam Following that logic we should go ahead and close every question  that is specific to Swift 1 and Swift 2 with that close reason because who's going to use those versions in the future when Swift 3 is the standard and "cutting edge".

Comment: Why you twist my words? You are claiming that *"The "A problem that can no longer be reproduced" close reason does not include the case when the problem was caused by a bug"*, I said that it does. Shift 1-2 isn't a bug (through many people would love to treat it that way). BTW, the most useful questions in SO are timeless ones, since no matter the year, people will still have them.

Comment: @Braiam — It doesn't. You have to take the second sentence in the context of the first sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure where I was twisting your words. When I say questions specific to older versions of Swift I really mean questions asking about problems caused by the language that were then resolved in future Swift versions. Maybe that is the misunderstanding. Would you say those should also be closed with this reason? As a sidenote: I agree that these questions aren't the crème de la crème of SO questions, or even remotely close, but that's not the point. It's about whether they are off-topic or not.

Comment: @Keiwan actually questions that endup being new bug in widely used tool/library have very good chance to represent the best of SO. Such questions can easily gather enough people to get even worst possible question in shape with necessary details. Example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632387/this-code-hangs-in-release-mode-but-works-fine-in-debug-mode/41634124#41634124

Comment: @Braiam while there are some cases when library must be of the latest version only to work it is not the common case. For example see statistics on current usage of JQuery 1.x - https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/js-jquery/1/all - there are still plenty of sites with older version. Not really sure what makes you believe that all libraries are updated as soon as fix is out. If you need any confirmation - search for "how to block Windows security updates" -for example - people try to avoid updates at all costs...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It largely reflects what I myself think. Followup: the new answers that appear years later, should be flagged as what.. VLQ? Custom mod flag? Perhaps all answers to this question are NAA and should be comments..?

Comment: @Dev-iL If the answer really only repeats someone else's answer and doesn't add anything new you can raise a custom mod flag and explain the situation. At least that's what I did once for an answer on one of my questions which then just got removed by a mod.